# Removing Default Text from TextArea created using @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I cannot remove the text from `@Html.TextAreaFor(x=>Model.name,new{Value ="",@class="test"})`

The Model.Name value is displayed inside the textarea. How do I create an empty textarea?

I also tried `@Html.TextAreaFor(x = >Model.name,new{ @Value="", @class="test" })` and `@Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.name, new{ @Text="", class="test" })`

Comment: Never try to override the `value` attribute when using the HtmlHelper methods. Just set the value of `name` to an empty `string` or `null` in the controller before you pass the model to the view

Comment: When you write `@Html.TextAreaFor(x=>Model.name)`, you're telling MVC this: _"(1) Display the text area containing the value of Model.name (2) If the text area is inside a form, then bind its contents to Model.name when the form is submitted"_ If you don't want any of these things to happen, then you shouldn't use `@Html.TextAreaFor`, use a simple `@Html.TextArea` instead

Comment: @holdenmcgrohen Thanks It worked